# Does gcc -static affect all provided libraries?

Tags: linux, gcc, ld

Does the gcc's option -static affect only one library that follows immediately  or does it affect all libraries provided on command line?

```
g++ -static -lutils1 -lutils2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GGC's [`-static` linkage option](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html#Link-Options) *prevents linkage with shared libraries*. So
*all* libraries that the linkage requires must be static. The
linker must be able to find a static library to resolve all `-lname` options that
are passed, as well as static versions of all default libraries that GCC silently
appends to the linkage.

That is the intended use of the `-static` option, although it is possible to make it more flexible.

GCC's `-static` option works simply by causing GCC to pass the option `-static|-Bstatic` to the linker (`ld`), at
a position in the generated `ld` commandline that precedes all the libraries in
the linkage.

The *linker's* `-static` option has a different meaning from GCC's. From [the `ld` manual](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Options.html#Options):

> -Bstatic
>
> -dn
>
> -non_shared
>
> -static
>
> Do not link against shared libraries. This is only meaningful on platforms for which shared libraries are supported.
>   he different variants of this option are for compatibility with various systems.
>   **You may use this option multiple times on the command line: it affects library searching for -l options which follow it.**

(My emphasis)

So the linker's `-static|-Bstatic` option means: Do not link any shared libraries *until further notice*. At a later
point in the `ld` commandline you may cancel the effect of `-static|-BStatic` with the option `-Bdynamic`, which
will allow dynamic libraries to be linked again, from that point on, *until further notice*.

Unlike the linker, GCC has no option that cancels the effect of its `-static` option. However, GCC allows you to pass abitrary options through to `ld`, via [`-Wl,<ld-options>`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html#Link-Options).
So you *can* in fact cancel GCC's `-static` option at a later point in the commandline like this:

```
gcc -static -o prog main.o -lfoo -lbar -Wl,-Bdynamic -lgum ...
```

This will generate a linkage commandline in which `-lfoo` and `-lbar` must be resolved to
static libraries but `-lgum` and any subsequent library can be resolved to
a shared library or a static library, as usual. Though if you wanted to "turn on/turn off"
dynamic linkage like this at different points in the commandline, it would be more
natural not to use GCC's `-static` option and instead write the equivalent:

```
gcc -o prog main.o -Wl,-Bstatic -lfoo -lbar -Wl,-Bdynamic -lgum ...
```